# Titanium: Set ID of a text field with titanium UI

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am working on titanium and creating view from controller. I have four fields and i need to set values with their IDs. Please check following code

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();

var first_name = Ti.UI.createTextField({
borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
color: 'black',
top: 10,
left: 10,
width: 250,
height: 60,
id:'first_name',
//value:data.first_name
});

row.add(first_name);

var tbl_data=[];
tbl_data.push(row);
var tbl= Ti.UI.createTableView({
data:tbl_data
});

$.home_view.add(tbl);
```

The id:'first_name' does not seem to work and i have not found any example where an ID is being assigned to any UI element. Please guide

Comment: do you want to set the value `first_name` as a value or hint text in text field?

Comment: I want to use id to set value of the field like $.first_name.value='some value'. where first_name id of the text field

Comment: No. It seems they do not have property of ID.

Comment: if you are creating in controller then just use `first_name.value`, do not use `$.first_name`. You can directly access it by its variable name.

Comment: Use variable name to set the value for  example first_name.value = "some_value".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set ID. But there are 2 options

1: Don't make an input in the controller, but make it a separate controller instead (see my [blogpost on reusable components](https://medium.com/@Wraldpyk/using-reusable-components-in-titanium-6927acb3e3e9))

2: Just set it like this:

```
$.first_name = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    color: 'black',
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    width: 250,
    height: 60
});
```

Then you can reference it later, like this: `$.first_name.value;`

You can also set a custom property to the `create` function (any property works fine) and identify it with that using events. Like this:

```
var field = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    color: 'black',
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    width: 250,
    height: 60,
    textFieldId: 'first_name'
});
field.addEventListener('blur',function(e){
    var id = e.source.textFieldId;
});
```